# Compare two word or excel or power point documents 2007 using PHP or Javascript programatically

Tags: php, excel, ms-word, compare, powerpoint

Following are some requirements for my new project.

Admin will upload a file which will be in format of Ms Word 2007 or Ms Excel 2007 or Ms Power Point 2007.

Lets say that admin has uploaded a file named demo1.docx file.

Now demo1.docx is a master file.

Now other users will upload their own files like demo2.docx, demo3.docx etc.

I want to compare demo2.docx and demo3.docx files with master file demo1.docx.

Files uploaded by other users must be copy of the master file. I mean number of characters, text, formatting have to be same as the master file.

If it is excel file, then number of sheets, no. of cells filled have to be same and same thing apply to power point files.

I want to do this using PHP or Javascript.

So can u please tell me if it is possible or not? and if it is possible then suggest me some ways to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes if they are exact copies, use `hash_file` function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

Comment: how to use this function to compare two files. give me example please

Comment: `if(hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile1) == hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile2))` they have to be identical, byte for byte.  Which may be to identical for you.  You could use `md5` too but i find `sha1` to be a tiny bit faster.

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: $file1 = "files/admin/first.docx";
$file2 = "files/users/first.docx";

if(hash_file('sha1', $file1) == hash_file('sha1', $file2))
{
    echo "match";
}
else
{
    echo "not match";
}

Comment: but it is not working.. both files have same content. but it give me not match on screen

Comment: Then they don't have the same content, if you do `if(hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile1) == hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile1))`  both file1 then they will be the same.  It's "Exact" Byte for Byte.  Which I specifically said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match them byte for byte the most efficient way is

```
if(hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile1) == hash_file('sha1', $pathToFile2))
```

if that's too exact, you could strip whitespace. From text files, not binary files like `docx` or `xlsx` files.

```
if(hash('sha1', str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents( $pathToFile1))) == hash('sha1', str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents( $pathToFile2))))
```

Or something like that to normalize the text.  For binary file types you will have to use some library for that type of file to convert them first to text.

In other words you will have to come up with some way to normalize the text contents of the file, such as upper casing everything and removing spaces or other acceptable differences.

Normalizing is a fancy way of saying, removing the differences.  A simple example is this.

```
Some text
```

Now is that the same as `Some text.`? Or `Some Text` or `some Text` that depends. But "normalizing them" may look like this `sometext` with no punctuation, spaces or casing.  It's up to you to decide how you normalize them.

Because of the mention of the binary formats I can't help you there as you will need to find a way to open them in PHP, which will require some 3rd party libraries.

Your question is very Broad, so I can only give you a Broad overview of how to do it.

Hashing is nice because it takes a file of {x} size and makes it 40 characters long (in the case of `sha1`) which is a lot easier to store in a DB, or visualize.  I mention the DB because you can cut the operation in half by pre-normalizing and hashing the Known file (the source file).  This will reduce the overall cost of comparing them.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example

```
echo hash('sha1', 'The same text') == hash('sha1', 'the same text') ? 'true' : 'false';
```

The output will be `false`  However if you do this:

```
echo hash('sha1', strtolower('The same text')) == hash('sha1', strtolower('the same text')) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

The output will be `true`

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6152a83ecb307769dfa76ed51a36eada7c391f34)

A small amount of text is no different then a large amount.  The difference between the two pieces of code above, is I normalized one and not the other.

**UPDATE1**

> ok. do u know the softwares like Typing Tutor.. which takes typing test. There is one fixed paragraph and user will write that paragraph in text box with same formatting.

```
$old = 'The same text';
$arr_old = explode(' ', $old);
$new = 'the same text';

$pattern = '/\b('.implode(')\b|\b(', array_map('preg_quote', $arr_old)).')\b/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $new, $matches );

print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => same
            [1] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => same
            [1] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => text
        )

)
```

It's important to mention that the index of the match(-1), will match the index of the word.  For example in the above there is no match in `$matches[1]` there is no match.  This corresponds to `The` which is the first item in `$arr_old = explode(' ', $old);` or `[0=>'The', 1=>'same', 2=>'text']` But because the match is `1` based and the array is `0` based you have to subtract 1.

PS to check these I would do something like

```
$len = count($matches);
for($i=1;$i<$len;$i++){
    if(!empty(array_filter($matches[$i]))) echo "match ".$arr_old[$i-1]."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
match same
match text
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34780731b555cbee194269ea4d3aba3dab1c9fef)

I hope that helps.

Comment: I cant use hash_file function, because I want to compare two files character by character.  because based on that comparision i will generate result of users. So using hash coded file how I will be able to find diffrences ??

Comment: I have no idea what this means `because based on that comparision i will generate result of users`.  You can compare them with a hash if you properly normalize the data.  How you do that depends on what you consider to be the same.  How much do they have to match. I have no way to know this.  I can only tell you what you could try, it's up to you to decide what you must do to make two different but similar things the same.

Comment: ok. do u know the softwares like Typing Tutor.. which takes typing test. There is one fixed paragraph and user will write that paragraph in text box with same formatting. after test is completed, software checks for accuracy and speed. my concept is much same as that but here I have to compare files and generate results based on that file comparision

Comment: Then you need to separate the words and compare them.  For that I would use preg_match_all.

Comment: preg_match_all will compare formatting of two files ??

Comment: See everything is possible, you just have to know what it is you really want.  I'm not Psychic, but I am a pretty good PHP programmer.

Comment: If your asking how to calculate the difference between each and every word, you may want to add something like [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) to the mix.  But this is getting way to broad.  This is not a trivial thing you are asking that can just be easily answered.